# How to populate a Flatlist from TextInput

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to populate a FlatList row with the value coming from a TextInput.
Below you can find my current code.

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet, 
StatusBar, FlatList } from 'react-native'

globalText = require('../styles/Texts.js');
globalColors = require('../styles/Colors.js');

class SearchInput extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  data: [],
  ingredients: ''
 }
}

_handleIngredients = (text) => {
 this.setState({ ingredients: text })
}

render(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content"/>
      <View>
       <TextInput style={[globalText.btnFlatPrimary, styles.inputText]}
         underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
         placeholder='Add ingredients'
         placeholderTextColor={globalColors.lightGrey}
         autoCapitalize='sentences'
         autoCorrect={false}
         autoFocus={true}
         onChangeText={this._handleIngredients}
         keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
        />
     </View>
     <FlatList
       data={this.state.data}
       renderItem={({text}) => (
         <View style={styles.cell}>
           <Text style={globalText.btnFlatPrimary}>{this.state.ingredients}</Text>
         </View>
       )}
     />
   </View>
  )
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  paddingTop: 20,
  backgroundColor: globalColors.white,
 },
 inputText: {
  paddingLeft: 16,
  paddingRight: 16,
  height: 60
 },
 cell: {
  height: 60,
  paddingLeft: 16,
  justifyContent: 'center',
 }
});

export default SearchInput;
```

---

I am probably missing something but if I pre populate the data and the ingredients states, then FlatList display correctly with the entered values. What I'd like it to populate the Flalist with the TextInput

```
data: [{key:'a'}],
ingredients: 'tomato'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flatlist will only re-render if the `data` property changes. If you want it to re-render based on other values, you would need to pass an `extraData` prop.

```
<FlatList
   data={this.state.data}
   extraData={this.state.ingredients} //here
   renderItem={({text}) => (
     <View style={styles.cell}>
       <Text style={globalText.btnFlatPrimary}>{this.state.ingredients}</Text>
     </View>
   )}
 />
```

Read more here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#extradata

Answer (score 0):

change: `onChangeText={this._handleIngredients}`

to: `onChangeText={(text) => this._handleIngredients(text)}`

This is for preserving the scope of `this`.

Comment: Thanks, that might be a start, but didn't solve it. I still can't display the input in the row

Comment: initializing the property like `_handleIngredients = (text) => {` handles this